# Evaluation of a multiple sum involving $\min\{i_0, i_1+ \cdots+ i_n\}$ with $i_1+ \cdots+i_n\leq x$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

How  can I calculate

> $\displaystyle\sum_{i_0=0}^x \sum_{i_1,\ldots, i_n=0}^1I_{i_1+
>  \cdots+i_n\leq x}\min\{i_0, i_1+ \cdots+ i_n\}$
>   as a function of $n,x$?

$I_{i_1+ \cdots+i_n\leq x}$ is indicator function which is 1 if $i_1+ \cdots+i_n\leq x$, else zero. 
Also $x<n$.

Now 
\begin{eqnarray}
\displaystyle\sum_{i_0}^x \sum_{i_1,\ldots, i_n=0}^1I_{i_1+
 \cdots+i_n\leq x}\min\{i_0, i_1+ \cdots+ i_n\}=\\
  \sum_{i_1,\ldots, i_n=0}^1I_{i_1+
 \cdots+i_n\leq x}\big( \sum_{i_0=0}^{i_1+\cdots+i_n}i_0 + \sum_{i_0=i_1+\cdots+i_n+1}^x i_1+ \cdots+ i_n\big ) 
\end{eqnarray}

But I can not proceed further due to indicator function. 
Kinly give me some hints.